# How to parse variable value in stored procedure in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, win32com, cx-oracle

I need some help in parsing variable value in stored procedure using python, below is the stored procedure

="call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE("**SGEPSBSH**",to_date('"&TEXT(**2022-06-01**,"DDMMMYYYY")&"','ddmonyyyy'),"**1110.9852**",NULL,NULL);"

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import re
import os
import pandas

import datetime as dt
from datetime import date

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = 'robin.hood'
EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING = 'SGEPSBSH Index Level'
EMAIL_CONTNT = {'Ticker': [], 'TickerLevel': [], 'DATE': []}

out_app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
out_namespace = out_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")


#lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
#lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')


root_folder = out_namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

out_iter_folder = root_folder.Folders['Email_Snapper']
#out_iter_folder = out_iter_folder.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime + "'")
item_count = out_iter_folder.Items.Count

Flag = False
cnt = 1
if item_count > 0:
    for i in range(item_count, 0, -1):
        message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]
        if EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING in message.Subject and cnt <=1:
            cnt=cnt+1

            Body_content = message.Body
            Body_content = Body_content[:Body_content.find("Regards")].strip()
            df = pd.DataFrame([Body_content])
            print(df.to_string())
            Ticker = df.to_string()[-82:-74]
            print(Ticker)
            price = df.to_string()[-8:]
            print(price)
            Date = df.to_string()[-21:-11]
            print(Date)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but I *think* you are asking about how to call a stored procedure? This can be found in the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#pl-sql-stored-procedures) and in the [samples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/plsql_procedure.py). In your case you should be able to do something like this:

```
cursor.callproc("CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE",
                ("SGEPSBSH", datetime.date(2022, 6, 1), "1110.9852",
                 None, None))
```

Comment: no no my question is related to how can i parse those values (SGEPSBSH, date:2022-06-01, Price: 1110.9852)  in store proc

Comment: Can you clarify in your question? What do you mean by "parse" those values?

Comment: parse means to pick values from dataframe into store proc like fill the blank values CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE("      ",to_date('"&TEXT( 
          ,"DDMMMYYYY")&"','ddmonyyyy'),"           ",NULL,NULL);"

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help much. If it is questions about how to get data out of data frames, you're better off asking on a Pandas site!